# How to replace value of a key from json object in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I am using postgres 9.5 and I want to replace the values of some keys from a json object. below is the json object :-

```
{
    "CollageName": "Test",
    "StudentDetails": [
        {
            "books": [
                {
                    "id": 101,
                    "name": "Test",
                    "price": 100
                },
                {
                    "id": 102,
                    "name": "Test2",
                    "price": 200
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And below is json object that holds key and value as :-

```
{
    "101": 2535,
    "102": 2536
}
```

What i want is the value for the keys 101 and 102 should be replace by 2535 and 2536 respectively.. And my final object should look like :-

```
{
    "CollageName": "Test",
    "StudentDetails": [
        {
            "books": [
                {
                    "id": 2535,
                    "name": "Test",
                    "price": 100
                },
                {
                    "id": 2536,
                    "name": "Test2",
                    "price": 200
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using to implement this?

Comment: @CoderGuy Postgres 9.5 with JAVA 8

Answer (score 0):

You should : 
- Loop on the the first object array "Books" items, then
- Foreach ITEM in "Books", you should : Loop on the key's names list (KEYS) of the second object then check whether : BOOK.ID = ParseToInt(KEY.NAME) and doing the necesseray update. You have to translate that into your used language.